# Remove Intro and Full Text in Tag Views

Tags: tags

I'd like to be able to click on a tag and only view the intro image, and the title. I'm hoping there is simple way to do this. I can handle an override if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom!

```
.tag-category .list-striped li img {
    max-width: 10%;
    width:100% !important;
}

.tag-body {
  display:none
}
```

The top part reduced the intro image, although I could have just started with a smaller intro image to begin with.

Hope this helps someone!